# logcat: FATAL EXCEPTION: main in GPS app

Tags: android, gps

Hi~ I just learned Android app for a while. My project is using googlemap to find my location (GPS)

The problem is the app can't work in my android. It display "sorry goooglegps(my project name) has been stopped!! "

Here is my logcat.

```
05-10 11:56:21.146: E/Trace(2547): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-10 11:56:21.226: W/dalvikvm(2547): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/googlegps/MainActivity; (481)
05-10 11:56:21.226: W/dalvikvm(2547): Link of class 'Lcom/example/googlegps/MainActivity;' failed
05-10 11:56:21.236: W/dalvikvm(2547): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c54540)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlegps/com.example.googlegps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlegps.MainActivity
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlegps.MainActivity
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1069)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
05-10 11:56:21.236: E/AndroidRuntime(2547):     ... 11 more
```

This problem is driving me crazy for a long time!! And I don't know which part has problem.
Can somebody help me? ><

PS. I has already put the three Internet permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Here are my code!
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlegps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />   

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlegps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spnLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt_select_location"
    />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:apiKey="0k2yDM6Bs-MFb8mDCA265joWiZOKsJNFbUjqw0w"
           android:clickable="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.googlegps;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager mLocationMgr;
    private String mBestLocationProv;

    private static String[][] locations = {
        {"台灣大學", "25.019943,121.542353"},
        {"清華大學", "24.795621,120.998153"},
        {"交通大學", "24.791704,121.003341"},
        {"成功大學", "23.000875,120.218017"}};

    private Spinner mSpnLocation;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private MapController mMapCtrl;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupViewComponent();

        setMapLocation();

        mLocationMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        mBestLocationProv = mLocationMgr.getBestProvider(c, true);

    }



    private void setupViewComponent() {
        mSpnLocation = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spnLocation);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        mMapCtrl = mMapView.getController();
        mMapCtrl.setZoom(18);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
            adapter.add(locations[i][0]);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpnLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpnLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(mSpnLocationOnItemSelLis);

    }

    private OnItemSelectedListener mSpnLocationOnItemSelLis = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setMapLocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    public void setMapLocation() {
        int iSelect = mSpnLocation.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String[] sLocation = locations[iSelect][1].split(",");
        double dLat = Double.parseDouble(sLocation[0]); // 南北緯
        double dLon = Double.parseDouble(sLocation[1]); // 東西經
        GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(dLat * 1e6), (int)(dLon * 1e6));
        mMapCtrl.animateTo(gp);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mMapCtrl.animateTo(new GeoPoint(
                (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1e6),
                (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1e6)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationMgr.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(mBestLocationProv, 60000, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        mBestLocationProv = mLocationMgr.getBestProvider(c, true);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mLocationMgr.removeUpdates(this);
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            mLocationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(mBestLocationProv, 60000, 1, this);
        }
}
```

Comment: Check that your activity is defined in the Manifest file and that you use the correct imports and package names in the Java file

Comment: sorry I don't understand. But I post my code so let be more clearly!

Comment: Did you follow Google Maps API [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_settings_in_the_application_manifest)? I can see missing information (like the Meta data for e.g.)

Comment: Num~ I'm not sure,but before I did this project I can write a project that can locate place . So I think google API is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into your manifest file inside application tag like this :

```
<application>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Comment: I add,but it still can't work!
(I add between application and infrom activity~)

Comment: Update the code written inside manifest and also update the Logcat . The messages inside the logcat must have changed. Try to clean your project and again build it.